# convert modsecurity apache specific rules for nginx

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, mod-security

Using [ModSecurity](http://modsecurity.org/) with [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) and [OWASP CRS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project) there are some rules which use apache specific directives like (in modsecurity_crs_55_application_defects.conf file):

```
Header edit Set-Cookie "^((?i:(_?(COOKIE|TOKEN)|atlassian.xsrf.token|[aj]?sessionid|(php)?sessid|(asp|jserv|jw)?session[-_]?(id)?|cf(id|token)|sid))=(?i:(?!httponly).)+)$" "$1; HttpOnly"
```

and

```
Header edit Set-Cookie "^((?i:(_?(COOKIE|TOKEN)|atlassian.xsrf.token|[aj]?sessionid|(php)?sessid|(asp|jserv|jw)?session[-_]?(id)?|cf(id|token)|sid))=(?i:(?!secure).)+)$" "$1; secure" env=secure_site
```

When using [Nginx](http://nginx.org/) instead of Apache, The nginx complains about these directives.

What are the equivalent rules for Nginx?

Comment: These rules just modifies `Set-Cookie` header to be `HttpOnly` and `secure`. You could (and should) just set them right in your application code. For PHP session see http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: The application is not in my hands